# Gradle execute tasks after one another

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

So I have the built in assembleDebug task in Android Studio. I wrote a custom task of mine, which increases the versionCode of the application, when I want to make an internal/external release.

Could someone tell me who can I call the assembleDebug task **after** my custom task execution completed (so version codes are increased in the file).

Answer (score 0):

You can add something like this to the very top of your app's build.gradle.

```
tasks.assembleDebug.dependsOn('myTaskName')
```

Or if this doesn't work because assembleDebug is added dynamically, this will:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug') {
        task.dependsOn 'myTaskName' 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your kind reply! Yes, but the problem with this approach is every time when assembleDebug will executed, it will increase the versionCode. What I want is just execute the versionCode from my custom task whenever I want and that will kick off assembleDebug.

Comment: Could you just run both tasks when you want to? `./gradlew myCustomTask assembleDebug`

Comment: Sure I could, but I am a lazy programmer who wants to click on one task only, which both increase the number and generate all the APKs.

Comment: I was going to say your task should just depend on assembleDebug, but its interesting because your task needs to happen before assembleDebug.

Comment: Use `finalizedBy` on your custom task with `assembleDebug` as argument.